# Query returning multiple objects when only one is expected

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple table:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AdmissionDateTime | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AdmissionEvent    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DischargeDateTime | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DischargeEvent    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DemographicId     | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| FacilityId        | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| VisitId           | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| WardId            | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

On which I run the following JPA (Spring-data) query:

```
@Query("SELECT w FROM WardTransaction w WHERE w.id = (SELECT MAX(x.id) FROM
WardTransaction x WHERE w = x AND w.visit = :visit)")
public WardTransaction findCurrent(@Param("visit") Visit visit);
```

On occasions I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: More than one
result was returned from Query.getSingleResult(); nested exception is
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: More than one result was returned from
Query.getSingleResult()
```

I have not been able to work out why this is happening.  It does not seem to make a lot of sense to me as there can only be one 'MAX' - especially on Id (I have used 'admissionDate' in the past).

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why are you selecting table ? you should select columns .

try this

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM WardTransaction w WHERE w.id in (SELECT MAX(x.id) 
   FROM WardTransaction x WHERE w.id = x.id AND w.visit = :visit)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is simpler and I think would get you what you want:

```
SELECT something
FROM sometable
Where something = someotherthing
ORDER BY sometable.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Basically it returns the results with the highest IDs at the top and grabs the first one.